# Improving Haskell code performance (BangPatterns, LazyByteString)

Tags: haskell

I've used BangPatterns, Lazy ByteString. Don't know what else to do to improve performance of this code. Any ideas and suggestions? It's clearly not the fastest version as it exceeds time limit.

```
-- Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below N
-- Input Format 
-- First line contains T that denotes the number of test cases. This is followed by T lines, each containing an integer, N.

{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -O2 -optc-O2 #-}
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import Control.Monad (mapM_)

readInt :: L.ByteString -> Int
readInt !s = L.foldl' (\x c -> 10 * x + fromIntegral c - 48) 0 s

main :: IO ()
main = do 
-- don't need the number of inputs, since it is read lazily.
-- split input by lines
  (_:ls) <- L.split 10 `fmap` L.getContents
-- length ls <= 10^5
  mapM_ (print . f . readInt) ls

-- n <= 10^9
f :: Int -> Int
f n = go 0 0
  where
    go !i !a | i == n            = a
    go !i !a | i `mod` 3 == 0
               || i `mod` 5 == 0 = go (i+1) (a+i)
    go !i !a                     = go (i+1) a
```

Comment: You can improve your performance vastly by using a better algorithm, which has the side effect of also reducing your code because of simplicity.

Comment: Have you profiled and/or looked at the GHC core that is generated?

Comment: There are some magic tricks for division by known divisors that GHC's native code generator doesn't use. This may well affect printing speed. You could try `-fllvm`. Also, you can generate multiples of 2 and 3 without doing any divisions, and you probably should.

Comment: @DonStewart, I wouldn't point a beginner toward Core as complicated as this would likely be, and I wouldn't do so without recommending some good options: `-ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dno-suppress-type-signatures` tends to give a pretty good signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: Without profiling your code, you're probably spending quite a bit of time testing every number to see if it's a multiple. Why don't you rethink this problem in terms of a hylomorphism, with an anamorphism generating an infinite lazy list of multiples of 3 and 5, and a catamorphism summing up to the number that you need? For the anamorphism, just use simple addition. You can generate two lazy lists, one for multiples of 3 and one for multiples of 5 and then join them together eliminating the duplicates. The catamorphism is a simple sum.

Comment: @fgv, it's possible to do even better than that. See my answer for details.

Comment: @dfeuer, absolutely. Good thinking about the wheel. At the core, it's still a hylomorphism, with an unfold followed by a fold. Now, given the fact that he needs the sums rather than the numbers, perhaps, with a bit of ingenuity, you could create a lazy list of sums (perhaps tuples with the number and the corresponding sum for that interval) and all you'd need to do at runtime is retrieve the sum directly from this list. And this would memoize any possible value that you'll ever need to retrieve (assuming that the input list is large enough to justify it).

Comment: @fgv, you make a very good point there, which leads to a very different point. While the wheel is a great way to make the numbers, we don't need the numbers at all, do we? We should be able to transform the wheel technique into a closed form!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

danidiaz has already [discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28783055/1477667) the input and output issue somewhat.

One fast way to produce multiples of 3 or 5 is to use a "wheel" of the sort commonly used for prime sieves.

```
multiples3or5 = go 0 $ cycle [3,2,1,3,1,2,3]
  where
    go n (x : xs) = n : go (n+x) xs
    go n [] = error "impossible"
```

In fact, since the circular list never ends, it's cleaner to use a different type. And since you're using `Int`, it might as well be specialized and unpacked for performance. Note that the `UNPACK` pragma in this context is not needed for GHC version 7.8 or above.

```
data IntStream = {-# UNPACK #-} !Int :> IntStream
infixr 5 :>

wheel :: IntStream
wheel = 3 :> 2 :> 1 :> 3 :> 1 :> 2 :> 3 :> wheel

multiples3or5 = go 0 wheel
  where
    go !n (x :> xs) = n : go (n+x) xs
```

As fgv [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782372/improving-haskell-code-performance-bangpatterns-lazybytestring/28786804#comment45846968_28782372), this is in the nature of an [anamorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphism#Anamorphisms_in_functional_programming). You can see this by writing

```
multiples3or5 = unfoldr go (0, wheel) where
  go (!n, (x :> xs)) = Just (n, (n+x, xs))
```

but note that `unfoldr` did not become efficient enough to be much use for anything until base 4.8, which has not officially been released.

When printing out the results, the system has to divide a lot of things by 10. I don't know if those routines are specially optimized, but I do know that GHC's native code generator does *not* currently optimize division by a known divisor unless that divisor is a power of 2. So you might find that you can improve performance by using `-fllvm`, and being careful to use a compatible version of LLVM.

#### Edit

See [Chad Groft's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798037/1477667) for a better way.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `print` in the line

```
mapM_ (print . f . readInt) ls
```

may be introducing some overhead, because `print` depends on the `Show` instance for `Int`, meaning a conversion to inefficient `String`s will take place.

Add the following imports

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Builder as BB
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import Data.List.Split (chunksOf) -- from the "split" package
import System.IO -- for stdout
```

and try to change that line with something like

```
let resultList = map (f . readInt) ls
F.mapM_ (BB.hPutBuilder stdout . F.foldMap BB.intDec) (chunksOf 1000 resultList)
```

that [takes chunks](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.2/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) of size 1000 from the list of `Int`s and uses the efficient [`Builder`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html) type and the specialized [`hPutBuilder`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.1/docs/Data-ByteString-Builder.html#v:hPutBuilder) function to write them to stdout.

(I added the chunking because otherwise I feared constructing the `Builder` would force the whole input list into memory. And we don't want that, because the list is being read lazily.)

I'm not sure if that's the main bottleneck, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're really concerned with efficiency, rethink the algorithm. Your main bottleneck is that you're manually summing a bunch of numbers between 1 and *N*, which will perform poorly on large *N* no matter what you do.

Instead, think mathematically. The sum of all multiples of 3 or 5 up to *N* is *almost* the sum of all multiples of 3 up to *N* (call this *S*_3), plus the sum of all multiples of 5 up to *N* (call this *S*_5). I say "almost" because some numbers get double-counted; call their sum *T*. Now the sum you want is exactly *S*_3 + *S*_5 – *T*, and each term has a nice closed formula (what is it?). Calculating these three numbers is much faster than what you're doing.

Comment: Yes I was totally ignorant of mathematics aspect of it. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Here you the formula without those "think about" mentor answers

```
sumMultiplesOf::Integral n=>n->n->n
sumMultiplesOf k n = d * (1 + d) `div` 2 * k where d = (n - 1) `div` k

sumMultiplesOf3or5::Integral n=>n->n
sumMultiplesOf3or5 n = sumMultiplesOf 3 n + sumMultiplesOf 5 n - sumMultiplesOf 15 n
```

Comment: This is a Project Euler problem. "Think about it" is the entire point.

Comment: @ChadGroft This is so very beginning of project euler so there is plenty of solutions out there. We are not hired as teachers to supervise requester's mind. This is more efficient to understand working code than to gain only advises to think by himself.